# What is the equivalent to autofacs "WithParameter" in DryIoc?

Tags: dryioc

In an effort to migrate from Autofac to DryIoc, I've run into a scenario whereby I need to pass a parameter value into the constructor of a service.

```cs
// given the following class
public class SomeService
{
    public SomeService(Foo foo, Bar bar) { }
}
```

```cs
// in autofac it looks like this
container.RegisterType<SomeService>()
         .WithParameter("foo", SomeFoo.Value)
         .WithParameter("bar", SomeBar.Value)
         .AsSelf();
```

What would the equivalent be in DryIoc?

Right now I'm attempting to use `RegisterDelegate`, but I'm not sure if I'm on the right path.

```cs
container.RegisterDelegate(x => new SomeService(SomeFoo.Value, SomeBar.Value));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cs
container.Register<SomeService>(
made: Made.Of(Parameters.Of
.Name("foo", _ => SomeFoo.Value)
.Name("bar", _ => SomeBar.Value)));
```

Here are possible overloads: https://www.fuget.org/packages/DryIoc.dll/4.2.0/lib/netstandard2.0/DryIoc.dll/DryIoc/Parameters

There is a similar  to `Parameters` `PropertiesAndFields` class to specify the property injection details.

In addition there is a DryIoc.Syntax.Autofac package you might be interested in https://www.fuget.org/packages/DryIoc.Syntax.Autofac.dll

As of V1 it covers only a small subset of Autofac API surface, but I encourage you to look into its source code and maybe help with PR ot two :)
https://github.com/dadhi/DryIoc/tree/master/src/DryIoc.Syntax.Autofac